# Can someone help me understand mongoDB indexing

Tags: mongodb, database

Currently, I am learning mongo and am reading up on indexing. I successfully made an index for "eyeColor" and when I ran this `db.users.find({"eyeColor":{$ne: "brown"}}).explain("executionStats")` I received the following:

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 7,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 8,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 7,
        ...
```

and when I ran this `db.users.find({"eyeColor":"brown"}).explain("executionStats")` I received the following:

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
        ...
```

I have 8 records in my collection. As I understand it, when I created my index that should have reduced the number of total documents examined, however, when I ran a search using `$ne` it seemed to have scanned for all. Not sure I understand how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#op._S_ne), `$ne` has low selectivity, so what you're seeing is expected. The query needs to examine all 8 `eyeColor` keys, determining that there are 7 keys with a value other than `'brown'`, and then read those 7 documents.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. And thank you for the link. Yours and this excerpt, from the docs, cleared it up ... "As a result, in many cases, a $ne query with an index may perform no better than a $ne query that must scan all documents in a collection."